# Scorecard absolute comparison with % symbol

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to make a comparison between two different dates in the GDS and present that information in a scorecard.

I have done this in the past with no problem, but this time I want to do an absolute comparison. Although I checked the box to make it an absolute comparison, the information appears with a % sign after it. I would like to see a "p.p." after it or nothing at all.

How can I achieve this result?

You can find below an image of what is happening.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I solved the issue by aligning all the elements of that scorecard to the right and adding a text box in front of the % sign. It is not perfect, but it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you're looking for, but I don't think this is currently possible. I had to add a disclaimer below the scorecards to indicate the comparison values are absolute (despite the percentages). Not ideal, but at least it shows the info

Comment: Hi, Filipe
I solved the issue by aligning all the elements of that scorecard to the right and adding a text box in front of the % sign. It is not perfect, but it works.
Thanks for your comment.